# Jquery scroll event fires only once

Tags: jquery

I know that there is a lot of questions and answers on the net but I can't still find the solution.
This code I have only triggers on the first scroll, after that nothing happens.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    currentScrollTop = $( window ).scrollTop();
    $( window ).scroll( scrollWindow );

});
function scrollWindow(){
    var newScrollTop = $( window ).scrollTop();
    var height = $( window ).height();
    if( currentScrollTop > newScrollTop ){
        var newPosition = currentScrollTop - height;
        $( "html, body" ).animate({ scrollTop: newPosition }, 600, function(){
            currentScrollTop = $( window ).scrollTop();
        });
    }
    else if( currentScrollTop < newScrollTop ){
        var newPosition = currentScrollTop + height;
        $( "html, body" ).animate({ scrollTop: newPosition }, 600, function(){
            currentScrollTop = $( window ).scrollTop();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything because `newScrollTop` will be equal to `currentScrollTop`, and your `if` condition doesn't cater for that.

Comment: Also, given that you've got the same logic in both branches of the `if` condition I'm not even sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: If scroll up then first if statement executes, if scroll down then second if statement executes.